# R Calculate row average, different columns for each row as indicated by another column

Tags: r

I want to calculate the row average of different columns for each row, as indicated by another column. In this example dataframe, the column "number" ranges from 1:11, and the other 12 columns are named "block_1" through "block_12".For example, if "block" is 5, I want to calculate the row average of columns block_6 through block_12. In other words, the average of the block number after indicated in "number" column, through block_12. Each ID represents a unique entry, all rows should be preserved.
How can I achieve this?

```
n <- 11 ; m <- 11 ; reps <- 12 
dff<-as.data.frame(cbind(matrix(sample.int(11, n, replace = TRUE), n, m/n), 
                    replicate(reps, sample(1:9, n, replace = TRUE)/10)))

myFun<- function(n = 5000) {
  a <- do.call(paste0, replicate(5, sample(LETTERS, n, TRUE), FALSE))
  paste0(a, sprintf("%04d", sample(9999, n, TRUE)), sample(LETTERS, n, TRUE))
}

dff$ID<-myFun(11)

dff<-data.table::setnames(dff, old = c('V1','V2','V3','V4', 'V5','V6','V7','V8','V9','V10', 'V11','V12','V13'), new = c('number','block_1','block_2','block_3','block_4', 'block_5','block_6','block_7','block_8','block_9','block_10', 'block_11','block_12'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one base R option :

```
cols <- grep('block', names(dff), value = TRUE)
n <- length(cols)

dff$mean_value <- mapply(function(x, y) mean(unlist(dff[x, cols[y:n]])), 
                         seq(nrow(dff)), dff$number + 1)
```